# How to delete specific line from a text file in c#?

Tags: line

I have a question. I am new here, so sorry if I did something wrong. I need to write a program which delete all comments (//, /**, */) lines from a text file. I wrote

```
 static bool BeKomentaru(string line, out string nauja) 

    {
        nauja = line ; //nauja is new(Im not from English speaking country)
        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length - 1; i++)
            if (line[i] == '/' && line[i + 1] == '/')
            {

                nauja = line.Remove(i);
                return true;
            }
        else if (line[i].ToString() == "/*"  && line [i +1].ToString() == "/")
            {
                nauja = line.ToString().Remove(i);
                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }
```

So, when the comment starts with //, my program delete it. But when comments are written with /** :

> /** Skaito, analizuoja ir rašo į skirtingus failus.
>    @param fv - duomenų failo vardas
>    @param fvr - rezultatų failo vardas
>    @param fa - analizės failo vardas */

I don't know how to write code, which go through all lines in comments, not only the first one. Because this line

```
    else if (line[i].ToString() == "/*"  && line [i +1].ToString() == "/")
```

doesn't work.

EDIT: when i changed line:

```
else if (line[i].ToString() == "/*"  && line [i +1].ToString() == "*/")
```

to:

```
else if (line[i].ToString() == "*"  && line [i +1].ToString() == "*")
```

it delete the first line "/** Skaito, analizuoja ir rašo į skirtingus failus."

but doesn't delete other commentd which don't have // or /**

Comment: I fixed title. Its c# :)

Comment: Your question is a little incomplete. What do you pass to the function? One line or the whole text? Also, I think it is a good thing to think of the logic of the program. When should it remove a line and when not?

Comment: I have a text file, with a program code. And in the code there are some comments. And I need to delete all comments. When comment are written with // its easy. But when comment is written with /** it's a little bit harder. Because my program delete line which start with // or **. But it doesn't delete other comments.
For example: /*/ Hello
I am writing
A new line
GoodBye/*/

So it only delete first line. And I need to delete all comment lines :)

Comment: Yes I understand that. But you need to think of an algorithm that will do what you want. Right now, you'r only looking for the first characters of the comments (`/*` and `//`) but as you said it should continue looping if the comment starts with `/*`.

Comment: Also another thing, image the code: `int a; //number of bla`. It will remove the whole line here so also the code in front of it.